# Best way to create a very simple discord bot=

Tags: python, python-3.6

Hey I really would know if It's possible to create a discord by a simple way ?

I got Actually this script but it crash a few time after I run it

```py
import discord
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("The bot is ready!")
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Making a bot"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content == "Hello":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "World")

client.run('***************************************************************')
```

And I get this error :

```
The bot is ready!Ignoring exception in on_ready

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Sigmanificient\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 270, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Sigmanificient\3D Objects\PyNG\discord_bot.py", line 7, in on_ready
    await client.change_presence(game=discord.Game(name="Making a bot"))
TypeError: change_presence() got an unexpected keyword argument 'game'
```

I would make multiples awnser for differents messages.

Comment: Does the bot need to be in python? Otherwise a good javascript tutorial I used before is https://www.digitaltrends.com/gaming/how-to-make-a-discord-bot/ (never had JS experience before)

Comment: I know only pyrhon so yes, it would be better for me

Comment: The error is pretty explanatory...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the game keyword was changed to activity

> https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/1125

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="Making a bot"))
```

It is possible you may need to capitalize `activity`

Answer (score 1):

Wherever you got that code from, make sure that you're using the same version of discord.py as they are. Otherwise you'll get errors. I just recently had to do a significant rewrite of one of my bots because it was using older code.

In this case, the game keyword argument in Client.change_presence was renamed to activity, so you're looking for something like:

```
await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(name="with the API"))
```

Comment: I use last versoon, I downloaded yeterday

Comment: I would go to the documentation and use the quckstart guide for whatever version you are using. All that that line is doing is setting the bot to be "playing" whatever game you want it to be. Dig through the documentation if you care, otherwise use the [quickstart guide](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#quickstart) to get going.

Comment: Ok but now it's crash when I send 'Hello' on discord

Comment: Again mate, dig through the documentation, Google the error you're getting.